# VB.NET - ToString() on nullable DateTime gives a strange value as a result

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have two dates :

- DateCreation, which is a DateTime
- DateCloture, which is a nullable DateTime

As you can see in the image below, the method ToString() on DateCreation gives a correct date, as well as the method ToString() on DateCloture.Value.
But ToString() on DateCloture leads to a inconsistent date (25/10/13629 03:47:29).

[image]

> I will use DateCloture.Value, but I would like to understand : Why the
>   ToString() method on a nullable Date gives an incorrect date as a
>   result ?

I am working with VB.NET and I am using entity framework to get datas from my MSSQL database.

***Note*** : This problem seams to be related to the debugger. The result is correct in the web page.

Thanks, 
Melodie

Comment: Have you clicked at the _refresh_ button in the debugger?

Comment: The `ToString` values in that image are stale (greyed) and needs to be refreshed

Comment: Yes, I have clicked the refresh button. The result remains the same. I have uploaded a new image in my question.

Comment: I have just added a note in my question : the result is correct in the web page so this problem seams to be related to the debugger.

Comment: can't reproduce with VS2015 Update 1.  What version are you using?

Comment: I am using VS Professional 2013, Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5.